# ¿Qué es Android NDK?

Tags: android

Por lo que entendí el Android NDK está orientado al desarrollo con `c` o `c++`, pero no entendí cómo funciona muy bien. Aplicaciones desarrolladas funciona multiplataforma? ¿Qué es exactamente ese Android NDK?

Comment: en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html?hl=es-419) se explica todo

Comment: En cuanto "¿Utiliza WebView o es nativo?" esto no tiene ninguna relación.

Comment: @Jorgesys He borrado esta pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Si miras la arquitectura del sistema operativo Android, las capas ART(la máquina virtual) y la HAL (la capa de abstracción de hardware) están basadas en código nativo (C y C++). Básicamente el NDK te permite utilizar codigo nativo en tu aplicación para poder interactuar con estas capas.

[image: Sistema operativo]

Con el NDK puedes crear interfaces que mapean el código escrito en C para interactuar con él desde Java.

La documentación:

https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html?hl=es-419

En mi caso lo he utilizado por ejemplo para leer el puerto serial en PDA Android que tienen lector de código de barras por ejemplo.
Espero que sea de utilidad. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Qué es exactamente ese Android NDK?

El [**Android NDK**](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) (Native Development Kit) permite a los desarrolladores utilizar código escrito en C/C++ en las aplicaciones Android a través de [JNI](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) (Java Native Interface).

Sin duda es más complejo que el uso del Android SDK pero la ventaja del uso del NDK es principalmente:

> •  Obtener un mejor y mayor rendimiento de un dispositivo para aplicaciones
>   de gran exigencia en términos computacionales, como los juegos o las simulaciones de física.
>
> • Puedes reutilizar tus propias bibliotecas C o C++, o las de otros desarrolladores.

---

> ¿Aplicaciones desarrolladas funciona multiplataforma?

En realidad una aplicación desarrollada no implica que sea multiplataforma, es propia para un dispositivo Android. En realidad el código C/C++ es el que puede ser usado en proyectos Android así como en proyectos iOS ya sea Objective C o Swift.

---

Este es un pequeño tutorial para usar el [**Android NDK**](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html):

Primeramente necesitamos instalar los siguientes paquetes necesarios para configurar el soporte NDK:

[image]

Cuando estos paquetes se encuentran instalados ve a tu archivo `local.properties` y agrega la ruta del NDK :+1:

> sdk.dir=C:\Users\jorgesys\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>   ndk.dir=C:\Users\jorgesys\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle

Ahora estas listo para trabajar con C/C++!

En tu proyecto puedes iniciar por crear el archivo para tu library nativa:

[image]

y la puedes llamar al iniciar tu aplicación de esta forma:

`static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
   }`

Para realizar el registro de un método implementado por tu library se realiza de esta forma:

public native String stringFromJNI();`

Ejemplo de prueba:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    public native String stringFromJNI();
    public native String stringCopyright();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }
}
```